# adding constraint on boolean field grails searchable plugin

Tags: grails, grails-searchable

I want to add constraint e.g "isEnabled" on domain property in `Grails` searchable plugin.I am using `Grails 2.4.4` and `searchable plugin 0.6.9`.currently I have added `string` fields in `searchable constraint` but not able to add constraint on the `Boolean` field.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: @Abhinandan i have made addition to my question

Comment: Can you show, how you have added the `constraint` for `string` fields in searchable?

Comment: Please add what `error` you are getting?